# Writing pandas to SQL Server via Linux server using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, sqlalchemy

I am able to successfully read from a SQL Server using the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db

sql_conn = db.connect('DSN=test4SERVER; UID=user1; PWD=abcdef')
query = '''
select * from testdb.dbo.Products
'''
data = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
sql_conn.close()
```

The data exists and I can successfully manipulate the data the way I want. But when I try to write to the same SQL Server via `sqlalchemy` like this:

```
data1 = data[['ProductId', 'Name']]
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(DSN=test4SERVER; UID=user1; PWD=abcdef) 
conn = engine.connect()
data1.to_sql('test_pyload2',con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

I am getting the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string DSN=test4SERVER; UID=user1; PWD=abcdef

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write back to SQL tables using pyodbc.
You could use something like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=Your_Server;DATABASE=YourDB;Trusted_Connection=yes')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()


for index, row in your_dataset.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT into yourSQLtable([column1],[column2]) values (?,?)",
                  row ['python_data_set_column1'],
                  row ['python_data_set_column2'])
cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you add encoding to the create_engine ?

```
driver = 'ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
enc='utf-8'
conn_string = r'mssql+pyodbc://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}?driver={4}?charset={5}'.format(username,password,server,dbname,driver,enc)
engine = create_engine(conn_string, encoding = enc)
df.to_sql(name=tablename, con=engine, chunksize=1000)
```